# Airflow/Amazon EMR: The VPC/subnet configuration was invalid: Subnet is required : The specified instance type m5.xlarge can only be used in a VPC

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, airflow, amazon-emr

I want to create an emr cluster triggered via Airflow on Amazon EMR. The emr cluster shows up in the UI of Amazon EMR but with an error saying:
**"The VPC/subnet configuration was invalid: Subnet is required : The specified instance type m5.xlarge can only be used in a VPC"**

Below is the code snippet and the config details in `json` format for this task that are used in the Airflow script.

My question is how can I incorporate the information (id codes) about VPC and subnet in the json (if this is even possible)? there are no explicit examples out there.

Hint: a network and an EC2 subnet is already created

```
JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES = {
    "Name": "sentiment_analysis",
    "ReleaseLabel": "emr-5.33.0",
    "Applications": [{"Name": "Hadoop"}, {"Name": "Spark"}], # We want our EMR cluster to have HDFS and Spark
    "Configurations": [
        {
            "Classification": "spark-env",
            "Configurations": [
                {
                    "Classification": "export",
                    "Properties": {"PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/usr/bin/python3"}, # by default EMR uses py2, change it to py3
                }
            ],
        }
    ],
    "Instances": {
        "InstanceGroups": [
            {
                "Name": "Master node",
                "Market": "SPOT",
                "InstanceRole": "MASTER",
                "InstanceType": "m5.xlarge",
                "InstanceCount": 1,
            },
            {
                "Name": "Core - 2",
                "Market": "SPOT", # Spot instances are a "use as available" instances
                "InstanceRole": "CORE",
                "InstanceType": "m5.xlarge",
                "InstanceCount": 2,
            },
        ],
        "KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps": True,
        "TerminationProtected": False, # this lets us programmatically terminate the cluster
    },
    "JobFlowRole": "EMR_EC2_DefaultRole",
    "ServiceRole": "EMR_DefaultRole",
}
```

```
create_emr_cluster = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(
    task_id="create_emr_cluster",
    job_flow_overrides=JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES,
    aws_conn_id="aws_default",
    emr_conn_id="emr_default",
    dag=dag,
)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `'Ec2SubnetId'` within the `Instances` object? Source: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.run_job_flow
I see it's a different library from the one you are using but many fields are very similar, so it might be the case that works fine for you as well

Answer (score 5):

EmrCreateJobFlowOperator calls `create_job_flow` from [emr.py](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/f692fc9c53c4031cf8d1eb6c0201bb3b5d383320/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/emr.py) which matches the same api from [boto3 emr client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.run_job_flow).

Therefore you can put an item `"Ec2SubnetId"` with your subnet id as value within the `"Instances"` dictionary.

This works for me on Apache Airflow 2.0.2